# Testing custom @Rule class

Tags: java, junit, rule

JUnit `@Rule` TemporaryFolder will delete the folder in case there is an `Exception` during execution of the test.

For my testing purposes I created my custom `@Rule` MyTemporaryFolder which is essentially the same except for when the `exception` happens it will save the temporary folder so the internals of the folder can be examined (basically any test output).

So now I have to write unit tests for my custom `@Rule` class. How can I do it? How can I simulate test starting and finishing inside of another test so I can check if my temporary folder was deleted properly (or is still there)?

Comment: Just call the appropriate methods on your rule in your test methods.

Comment: You could advise JUnit to store the temporary folder on the Desktop (or somewhere else). You can debug your tests and see how the folder appears/disappears. On how to write tests with @Rule please refer to one of the various tutorials in the internet.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27042951/eclemma-code-coverage-plugin-and-powermockrunner).