# Junit code coverage in not covering the code in java using eclemma

Tags: junit, code-coverage

I have written the junit test case of a API helper class but when I am checking the code coverage, the helper class is showing as 0 percent. I am not sure what is the issue.

Here is the sample code:

```
public Class ClassHelper{
   public Response invoke() {

   ClassVO classVO = new ClassVO(pString);
   ClassOutputVO outputVO = getSoapServiceBridgeProvider().getSoapServiceBridge(classVO).invokeProces()
...
  return response
  }
}
```

the testclass is given below:

```
@Test
public void testInvoke() throws Exception{
PowerMockito.whenNew(ClassVO.class).withArguments(Mockito.anyString()).thenReturn(mockVO);

Response actualResponse = (Response) classHelper.invoke();
```

can someone please help me with the issue? Its working with other helper classes but only happening with api helpers.

the working example has below:

```
 @Component
 public class TestHelper {
 public Reponse updateRole(Request request) throws Exception {
       ClassVO vo = new ClassVO();
       vo.setRoleId(request.getRoleId());
       vo.setRoleName(request.getRoleName());
       Response response = new Response;
                response.setRoleId(vo.getRoleId());
                response.setRoleName(vo.getRoleName));
 }
 }
```

Test class:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
@PrepareForTest({ DriverManager.class })
public class TestHelperTest { 
 @InjectMocks
 private TestHelper testHelper;

 @Test
 public void testUpdateRole() throws ADTMBaseException{
    Request request = new Request();
    request.setRoleId(8);
    request.setRoleName(JUnitTestConstants.ROLE_NAME);
    Reponse actualResult = testHelper.updateRole(request);
}
```

Comment: Please show more details of your code. Show us your test and the code to be tested please. Try to give us a minimalistic example.

Comment: Hello Chris311, I have added some more code for your understanding. I hope this can help.

Comment: EclEmma does't work with PowerMock as you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27042951/eclemma-code-coverage-plugin-and-powermockrunner)

Comment: ohh, but how come its working for my other helper classes. Its only happening with api helpers.

Comment: Can you please show the example where it is working.

Comment: @Chris311, I shared the working example above. Please have a look on this

Comment: I don't get it: You mock your class to be tested `TestHelper`...why?